# ForEach Loop requires that Image Conform to 'Hashable' when trying to show an array of Images?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach, swiftui-image

I'm trying to create a view, that allows the user to upload multiple images and display them in a HStack. I'm able to display a singular image by simply putting:

`image?.resizable().scaledToFit()`
So in order to display multiple images, I thought to append it to an array `loadImages()`, and use a ForEach loop in order to display the images, by defining a

`@State private var images: [Image]? = []`, and using `images?.append(image)` to add it to the `images` array.

Since it's an optional, in my ForEach loop, I unwrapped it with an empty array, but this is where I get the error `Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Image' conform to 'Hashable'`. To my understanding, by adding `id: \.self` should allow it to conform to Hashable already - is there any special properties that Image contains that prevents it from conforming to `Hashable`, or is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

For reference, the full code is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePickerTestView: View {
    
    @State private var images: [Image]? = []
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var isShowingImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary)
                    
                    Text("Tap To Select Photos")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    isShowingImagePicker = true
                }
                HStack {
                    ForEach(images ?? [], id: \.self) { img in
                        img
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    }
                }
                /*
                //insert code to display images here
                //old implementation was
                image?
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                 */
                
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
            .navigationTitle("Select Images")
            .onChange(of: inputImage) { _ in
                loadImages()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker) {
                ImagePicker(image: $inputImage)
            }
        }
    }

    func loadImages() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        let image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
        images?.append(image)
    }
}



#Preview {
    ImagePickerTestView()
}
```

and the imagePicker is:

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            
            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }
            
            if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
                    self.parent.image = image as? UIImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, which simply allows you to select a photo.

Comment: Why is `images` an optional? Arrays are supposed to be declared as non-optional empty.

Comment: `Image` is a `View` views dont belong in arrays, you can use `UIImage` but not `Image`

Comment: @loremipsum Does that rule apply to all objects that implement ```View```? What about an array of ```Color ```?

Comment: @BenzyNeez IMO it does, I know others use it but if you look at documentation Color is a representation of color and UIColor is a representation of color data. Why should Color that doesn’t have the ability to represent data be in the data layer? I could go on and on, the just don’t belong.

Comment: @loremipsum Interesting. All ```Gradient``` initializers that take an array of ```Color``` would need to be deprecated then.

Comment: @BenzyNeez gradient is a ShapeStyle only useful to the presentation layer it does not cross into the data layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution might be to wrap each image with an `Identifiable` wrapper. For example:

```swift
struct IdentifiableImage: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image: Image
}
```

If the array is then changed to be `[IdentifiableImage]`, the `ForEach` can be simplified to the following:

```swift
ForEach(images) { img in
    img.image
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> To my understanding, by adding id: .self should allow it to conform to Hashable already

This is the reason you are struggling. with `id: \. ...` you are marking what property of your collection item what should be used to *identify* your individual items. This property has to conform to `Hashable`. By using `self` and an `Image` as collection item `Image` would need to conform to `Hashable` what it does not.

As allready pointed out in the comments, SwiftUI Views are not intended to be used in Arrays or be stored in any other way. Store the source for the View and build it when necessary.

The easiest way would be to create a model struct that conforms to `Identifiable`.

e.g.:

```
struct ImageModel: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var image: UIImage
}
```

than a possible implementation would look like:

```
struct ImagePickerTestView: View {
    
    @State private var images: [ImageModel] = []
    @State private var isShowingImagePicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary)
                    
                    Text("Tap To Select Photos")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    isShowingImagePicker = true
                }
                HStack {
                    ForEach(images) { model in
                        Image(uiImage: model.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
            .navigationTitle("Select Images")
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker) {
                // instead of an selection variable pass on the model array
                ImagePicker(images: $images)
            }
        }
    }
}



#Preview {
    ImagePickerTestView()
}

import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    // change implementation from single var to array
    @Binding var images: [ImageModel]
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            
            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }
            
            if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
                    // Check if an image has been selected
                    guard let image = image as? UIImage else {return}
                    // append the model
                    self.parent.images.append(ImageModel(image: image))
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```